# How to streamline code with a for statement

Tags: python, django

I am trying to find the number of students enrolled by teacher. The code below produces the result I want. However, the code seems to be inefficiently long. I tried to simplify the code by using a "for" functiib, but couldn't solve it, so I posted a question to the experts for help.

The number registered in SPECIAL CLASS must be obtained separately.

The register condition is student with 1 entered in the day field.

```
monthly_kwargs = {
    'jan': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-01-01', register_date__lte='2022-01-31')),
    'feb': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-02-01', register_date__lte='2022-02-28')),
    'mar': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-03-01', register_date__lte='2022-03-31')),
    'apr': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-04-01', register_date__lte='2022-04-30')),
    'may': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-05-01', register_date__lte='2022-05-31')),
    'jun': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-06-01', register_date__lte='2022-06-30')),
    'jul': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-07-01', register_date__lte='2022-07-31')),
    'aug': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-08-01', register_date__lte='2022-08-31')),
    'sept': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-09-01', register_date__lte='2022-09-30')),
    'oct': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-10-01', register_date__lte='2022-10-31')),
    'nov': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-11-01', register_date__lte='2022-11-30')),
    'dec': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-12-01', register_date__lte='2022-12-31')),
    'total': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__year=today.year)),
    'SPECIAL_jan': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-01-01', register_date__lte='2022-01-31', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_feb': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-02-01', register_date__lte='2022-02-28', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_mar': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-03-01', register_date__lte='2022-03-31', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_apr': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-04-01', register_date__lte='2022-04-30', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_may': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-05-01', register_date__lte='2022-05-31', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_jun': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-06-01', register_date__lte='2022-06-30', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_jul': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-07-01', register_date__lte='2022-07-31', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_aug': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-08-01', register_date__lte='2022-08-31', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_sept': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-09-01', register_date__lte='2022-09-30', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_oct': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-10-01', register_date__lte='2022-10-31', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_nov': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-11-01', register_date__lte='2022-11-30', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_dec': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__gte='2022-12-01', register_date__lte='2022-12-31', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL)),
    'SPECIAL_total': Count('student_id', filter=Q(register_date__year=today.year, student__class__id__in=SPECIAL))
}
value_list_args = ['teacher__first_name', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sept', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'total',
                   'SPECIAL_jan', 'SPECIA_feb', 'SPECIA_mar', 'SPECIA_apr', 'SPECIA_may', 'SPECIA_jun', 'SPECIA_jul', 'SPECIA_aug', 'SPECIA_sept', 'SPECIA_oct', 'SPECIA_nov', 'SPECIA_dec', 'SPECIA_total']

monthly_enroll = DayCheck.objects.filter(Q(day='1', register_date__year=today.year)) \
            .values('teacher__first_name').distinct() \
            .order_by('teacher__first_name') \
            .annotate(**monthly_kwargs) \
            .values_list(*value_list_args) \
            .order_by('teacher__first_name')

monthly_enroll_list = [];
for i in monthly_enroll:
    inside_list = []
    for j in i:
        inside_list.append(j)
    monthly_enroll_list.append(inside_list[0:27])
```

[Add Question] With someone help, the original problem was solved. I'm using this code under different conditions depending on the parameter. The code below works well without errors on the local PC, but when I update the server, "Cannot resolve keyword 'jan' into field." An error occurs. Moving the indent to various places doesn't work on the server. The important thing is that it doesn't always throw an error in the first place. 1. sudo systemctl daemon-reload 2. sudo systemctl restart uwsgi is uploaded to the server. The function works normally, but if I enter after a few minutes, the above error occurs. What's the problem?

```
parameter = request.GET.get('parameter')
if not request.GET or parameter == 'ALL';
    monthly_enroll = DayCheck.objects\
.filter(Q(day='1', register_date__year=today.year))\
.values('teacher__first_name').distinct().order_by('teacher__first_name')\
.annotate(**monthly_kwargs).values_list(*value_list_args)\
.order_by('teacher__first_name')
else:
    monthly_enroll = DayCheck.objects\
.filter(Q(day='1', register_date__year=today.year, uploader_id__contact__team=paramter))\
.values('teacher__first_name').distinct().order_by('teacher__first_name')\
.annotate(**monthly_kwargs).values_list(*value_list_args)\
.order_by('teacher__first_name')

monthly_enroll_list = [list(i)[0:27] for i in monthly_enroll]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems like it may have been adapted from JavaScript, given the number of dot operators dangling off of `DayCheck`. Nevertheless, here are some ideas:

- If the order of items in `monthly_kwargs` doesn't matter, then you can loop over months to save some lines (though I'm not sure it's actually *clearer* or easier to read that way.
- The `monthly_enroll_list` can be turned into a very concise list comprehension, so that's good!

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

monthly_kwargs = {}
for i in range(1, 13):
    gte = datetime(2022, i, 1)
    lte = datetime(2022 + i // 12, (i + 1) % 12, 1) - timedelta(1)
    mo = f'{gte:%b}'.lower()
    monthly_kwargs[mo] = Count('student_id', filter=Q(
        register_date__gte=f'{gte:%Y-%m-%d}',
        register_date__lte=f'{lte:%Y-%m-%d}'
    ))
    monthly_kwargs['SPECTIAL_' + mo] = Count('student_id', filter=Q(
        register_date__gte=f'{gte:%Y-%m-%d}',
        register_date__lte=f'{lte:%Y-%m-%d}', student__class__id__in=SPECIAL
    ))
monthly_kwargs['total'] = Count('student_id', filter=Q(
    register_date__year=today.year
))
monthly_kwargs['SPECIAL_total'] = Count('student_id', filter=Q(
    register_date__year=today.year, student__class__id__in=SPECIAL
))
value_list_args = [
    'teacher__first_name', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may',
    'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sept', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'total',
    'SPECIAL_jan', 'SPECIA_feb', 'SPECIA_mar', 'SPECIA_apr', 'SPECIA_may',
    'SPECIA_jun', 'SPECIA_jul', 'SPECIA_aug', 'SPECIA_sept', 'SPECIA_oct',
    'SPECIA_nov', 'SPECIA_dec', 'SPECIA_total'
]
monthly_enroll = DayCheck.objects\
    .filter(Q(day='1', register_date__year=today.year))\
    .values('teacher__first_name').distinct().order_by('teacher__first_name')\
    .annotate(**monthly_kwargs).values_list(*value_list_args)\
    .order_by('teacher__first_name')

monthly_enroll_list = [list(i)[0:27] for i in monthly_enroll]
```

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of time. Thank you so much for the detailed and concise reply. But I faced another problem. I've corrected the question, so please take the time to check it out.